# Extract text from link in imacros

Tags: imacros

This is my HTML tags

```
<div class="labValu">
<a id="project-link-16363353" class='stop-propagation' href="/Haware-Pinnacle-Kalyan-West-Thane-pdpid-4d4235303831393334" target="_blank">Haware Pinnacle</a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to extract the text "**Haware Pinnacle**" .So I tried doing

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=a ATTR=target:_blank&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
```

But I get this text "Post Property Free" 
Also I tried with

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:link EXTRACT=TXT
```

So this gives me

#EANF# 
How should I go about this one. 
Any help will be much appreciated ..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution:

`TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT`

You will need to know the position of the Anchor that you're trying to extract.  So if it's always the 1st link, then the above code would work. If it was the 7th link, then the code below would work.

`TAG POS=7 TYPE=A ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT`

However, if the location of the link is dynamic, then you'll have to use relative positioning (like `POS=R1`), which can be explained in more detail here: http://wiki.imacros.net/Data_Extraction#Extract_with_relative_Positioning  I suggest that you locate a tag that is always easy to identify, and then find the relative location of the link you're trying to extract from there.  The code below will look for the next available hyperlink relative from it's current position and extract the text.

`TAG POS=R1 TYPE=A ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT`